# Rails mailer alternating old and new layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, nginx, mailer

I created new production instances with rails app, that use nginx, sidekiq and redis.

After this, I removed old instances inside Load Balance and I added new instances with new release.

The new release remove all mailer layout, but my app send some e-mails with old layout and it send some e-mails with new layout.

Somebody knows how solve this?

Comment: Are any of your sidekiq workers running old servers? Are all of your sidekiq workers on the newest servers running on the latest production code?